# ReactJS changing background color

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I removed all unnecessary parts of my project just to show the core problem of what I am having trouble with.
App.css

```
.App{
  background-color: aqua;
}
.AboutMe{
  color:blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="AboutMe">
          Akshay Gulabrao<br/>
          aksgula22@gmail.com<br/>
          +1 (818) 518-8295<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expect the background to show aqua (light blue), but what happened was that I got no background.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `"App"` `div` doesn't take up the whole height of the screen.

Try setting the `height` to `100vh` ([a relative unit of measurement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages), equals 100% of the viewport's height):

```css
.App {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100vh;
}
```